# Ruby on Rails routes.rb not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, routes

I'm upgrading an existing Rails app. I want to add a new route to the routes.rb file, that links to a function in a controller. Excerpt from the original *working* routes.rb file:

```
match 'items/:id/add_to_collection/:collection_pid'     =>  'items#add_to_collection', :via => [:get, :post]
```

Controller file:

```
  #add to a task
  def add_to_collection
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    @collection_pid = params[:collection_pid]

    #does the item have a RELS-EXT datastream?
    @rels_ext_ds =  RELS_EXT_Datastream.new(:id => params[:id])
    if !@rels_ext_ds.nil?
         @rels_ext_ds.add_relation("fedora:isMemberOfCollection",{"rdf:resource","info:fedora/" + @collection_pid})
         @rels_ext_ds.save_to_fedora
    end
    render :text => "OK"
 end
```

I want to add a function that does something similar, so I add to the routes.rb file:

```
match 'items/:id/add_to_event/:event_pid'       =>  'items#add_to_event', :via => [:get, :post]
```

And to the controller file:

```
  #add to an event
  def add_to_event
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    @event_pid = params[:event_pid]

    #does the item have a RELS-EXT datastream?
    @rels_ext_ds =  RELS_EXT_Datastream.new(:id => params[:id])
    if !@rels_ext_ds.nil?
    @rels_ext_ds.add_relation("fedora:isMemberOfEvent",{"rdf:resource","info:fedora/" + @event_pid})
    @rels_ext_ds.save_to_fedora
    end
    render :text => "OK"
  end
```

When I run the application however (after restarting Apache), the application redirects and doesn't call the function. From the log file:

```
Started GET "/app/items/123456/add_to_event/testerevent" for 192.168.102.22 at Tue Apr 08 15:42:18 +0200 2014
Processing by ItemsController#add_to_event as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"tcmp:123456", "event_pid"=>"testerevent"}
Redirected to https://localhost/app/login
Completed 302 Found in 87ms
```

Do I need to restart some other service, rebuild the app somehow or clear some cache? I know my function content in the controller is 100% correct because when I replace the original function's content with the new function's content, everything works fine. I tried to print some log in my new function, but there is no log find to be found, indicating the function was never called. It seems to be matching in the log file though. Am I overlooking something here? I'm fairly new with RoR. Thanks!

EDIT:

I found out which function redirects my app to the login page. Is a function called check_authorization in the application_controller.rb file.

```
def check_authorization
  user = User.find(session['user'])
  unless user.roles.detect{|role|
    role.rights.detect{|right|
      right.action == action_name && right.controller == self.class.controller_path
    }
  }
  flash[:notice] = "Please log in to access the page you requested. (action "+action_name.to_s+", controller "+self.class.controller_path.to_s+")"
  #request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] ? (redirect_to :back) : (redirect_to :controller => 'users',:action=>'login') <-- This function
end
```

The weird thing is, I really am logged in.

Comment: ... It's telling you you have to log in.

Comment: Are you using cancan?
If you do, you have to add your method in your abilitys file...

Comment: show us the routes.rb file

Comment: I'm not using the cancan gem. The weird thing is I am logged in and the original function works. When I modify the routes.rb file to redirect the new route to the original function, and the original route to the new function, like so:

    `match 'items/:id/add_to_collection/:event_pid'          =>      'items#add_to_event', :via => [:get, :post]`
    `match 'items/:id/add_to_event/:collection_pid'          =>      'items#add_to_collection', :via => [:get, :post]`

The new (2nd) route works but the first one does not.

Answer (score 0):

first you check any engine you are using or not like cancan.

see in log file `"app/items/123456/add_to_event/testerevent"` it is redirected,so
change the route and check this is correct or not don't know please try once

add "/" in-front of route.

```
match '/items/:id/add_to_event/:event_pid'       =>  'items#add_to_event', :via => [:get, :post]
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but adding the slash didn't solve the problem. I don't think the route itself is the problem (see my comment above)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It had nothing to do with the routing file or the function whatsoever, it was some right not granted in the user configuration. Thanks for the effort anyway!